# Loading Fonts.com Web-Font Doesn't work in Chrome (but only when deployed?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, fonts, gatsby

I'm currently hosting a React/Gatsby project via GitHub Pages, and I've been messing with fonts.com and their web-fonts system to get the Rockwell font. I followed the instructions of inputting the script tag into the  section of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//fast.fonts.net/jsapi/0a390850-37c6-420c-8ead-c15e81202559.js"></script>
```

I followed all of their advice when referencing my domains, and I've run into this interesting bug.

1. <s>The font loads perfectly normally in Firefox.</s>

   a. UPDATE: This was not true, it was cached there too.
2. The font also loads when I run 'gatsby develop' and have my project running in localhost:8000

   a. (I know that it works in localhost because I use the nifty "empty cache and hard reload" function of Chrome.)
3. And yet, when I pull the page up in Chrome, I get the following error

   ```
   GET https://fast.fonts.net/dv2/14/8dd355f9-1a9a-4d91-8aa1-7dcc9deeb439.woff2?d44f19a684109620e4841578a490e8187cac2bf7466ecccd35f843ec9e8410dc73fea4cea7acbbbaf9d830e48fc615a792f4b24a1c10853efb77f66879fc39a15a09593f079cf7a38cb48dd4836fa2ebba1b54d33b577d893508a6f4d0526453533728dec4671fee2d130ac32d5b8a97d5&projectId=0a390850-37c6-420c-8ead-c15e81202559 net::ERR_ABORTED
   ```

So either that will show up, or I get a 403 error. (I've followed their posted advice on solving 403 errors.)

I've Googled and messed around to no avail. I found a similar problem suggesting to use an @import in the css, but that doesn't work because it's a javascript file

As far as I can tell, it has something to do with loading the woff2 part of the font in particular, but I can't take that part out because it's a web font. Somehow that's resulting in a net::ERR_ABORTED. Could it have something to do with how Gatsby publishes? Or maybe how React handles having script tags in the ?

Thanks for any advice you can give!

UPDATE: Firefox had it cached. This leads me to believe that Webpack is messing with the script tag/downloaded stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I solved this.
While the project was being hosted on a project domain (www.mywebsite.com/project), I saw deep in the network calls that the request itself was coming from the regular domain (www.mywebsite.com). So I had to adjust that in the listed domains.